# Bash linux loop throu file and send email

Tags: linux, bash, scripting, informatica

I have a file which have in every row email recipient,header and body .
So the structure is like that:

```
receipient|header|body

george@gmail.com,Alertheader,CheckYourData

rafal@gmail.com,GreenLight,GoWithYourProcess
```

I would like to write a script which process every row and send an email to each person with header and body.

Please keep in mind that i am writing it on Informatica ETL tool (if that makes any difference)

So below script is working for sending email to 1 person from file(so file just have 1 email and nothing else),but got stuck on multiple persons and how to loop thru all those values.

```
echo "Please check the session log in /ciwetl/SessLogs directory.CIW-SUPPORT TEAM" | mailx -s "CIW : Workflow wf_m_LOAD_CIW_LOCATION_RT failed." `cat /filelocation/emailsrc.txt`
```

EDIT:
I have this working with this script :)

```
cat 'location/emailsrc.txt' | while IFS=, read -r line line2 || [[ -n $line ]]; do  echo $line2 | mailx -s "CIW : Workflow wf_m_LOAD_CIW_LOCATION_RT failed." $line; done
```

But there is another thing i didnt anticipated ....
In a body we can have commas so that would probably ruin my file.I was thinking to change delimiter in file to | .
I tried to change IFS=| but that didnt work out. Any tips ?

Comment: What have you tried so far ?

Comment: @rafalbballer: the one-liner written by you doesn't prints "header" and "body" in the mail, it only prints the message given in your `echo`. is it the same what you want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the following to include the 'header' and 'body' from the file

```
IFS=',' while read email header body ; do
   if [ "$email" ] ; then
      mailx -s "$header" $mail <<< "$body"
   fi
done < /location/emailsrc.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

So while i posted it i almost immediatly found a solution :

```
cat '/location/emailsrc.txt' | while IFS='|', read -r line line2 || [[ -n $line ]]; do  echo $line2 | mailx -s "CIW : Workflow wf_m_LOAD_CIW_LOCATION_RT failed." $line; done
```

Comment: Good job @rafalbballer